# Можно ли сохранять запросы в pgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql

Есть запросы которые будут использоваться пару раз в виде под запросов, но сохранять их в файлах на компьютере и потом искать и копировать  не очень удобно!

**Как можно сохранять запросы в самом pgAdmin3 и возможно ли это ?**

*Спасибо !*

Comment: как правильно сохранить базу данных в pgAdminIII,чтобы потом ее можно было показать на другом компе??

Answer (score 3):

`Query Tool (вызывается CTRL + E) > Favourites > Add favourite`

Если вам потребуется перенести эти запросы на другой компьютер, то они сохраняются в обычном XML файле. Увидеть где он находится можно в `File > Options > Query tool  > Favourites`

Comment: Столько кнопок. Проще файл найти

Answer (score 2):

Сохранить в программе, наверняка, можно, но на мой вкус грамотнее пользоваться функционалом самого Postgres — [`VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createview.html). Суть та же, что и сохранение подзапроса в файлик с постоянным ручным копированием, но более точной аналогией будет функция в программировании. Из плюсов: читать запросы проще, файлик может потеряться, `VIEW` бэкапится вместе со всей базой и его легче поменять.

---

На примере. Есть таблица `users`, помимо прочего в ней содержится поле `active Boolean`. Мы хотим выбрать адреса электропочты активных пользователей. Вариант "в лоб" — `select email from users where active`, но если наше определение "активности" поменяется (к примеру, заходил на сайт в течение недели), придётся менять код везде и запрос не будет выглядит таким простым, особенно внутри более сложных `SELECT`ов.

```
-- чтобы упростить себе жизнь в будущем, создадим представление (VIEW):
create view active_users as select * from users where active;

-- использовать просто:
select email from active_users;
```

Пример, конечно, тривиальный, но суть должна быть понятна. Есть ещё [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-creatematerializedview.html), который не только "разворачивает подзапрос", а ещё и хранит результаты в таблице для повышенной производительности (со своими минусами, конечно).